# How can I preserve date field format when importing to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, import

I have a slight learning curve working here, is there a work around to importing spread sheet data without changing the type of data in the fields? i am importing some water test data along the rio grande and everything comes in fine except for the date field. date is formatted xx/xx/xxxx.

Comment: How did you imported your data? Did you used a specific plug-in? CSV import or you attached one excel table?

Comment: i used the plugin XYtools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joshua, I suggest using a .csvt file, which is described nicely by @underdark in [How to Specify Data Types of CSV Columns for use in QGIS](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/how-to-specify-data-types-of-csv-columns-for-use-in-qgis/).

Comment: that does it, now to join and visualize.